# How to set 2 lines of attribute string in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I want to set attributed text in my `UILabel`. It should be 2 lines. So I made 2 attributed strings like this.

```
var myMutableTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.init(name: fontBold, size: 15.0)!])
var mutDj=NSMutableAttributedString(string: dj!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.init(name: font, size: 15.0)!])
```

How can append these two attributed string to display in 2 lines like

```
Title
DJ name
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **\n** to the second attributed text

```
var myMutableTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.init(name: fontBold, size: 15.0)!])
var mutDj= NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n \(dj)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.init(name: font, size: 15.0)!])
myMutableTitle.appendAttributedString(mutDj)

yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
yourLabel.attributedText = myMutableTitle
```

Comment: Thanks but im having a small issue this dj name comes as optional("name of the dj") how can I fix this?

Comment: just add \(dj!)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating 2 `NSMutableAttributedString` you can create single one like this.

```
let str1 = "\(title!) \n(dj!)"
let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str1)
attributedStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.init(name: fontBold, size: 15.0)!, range: (str1 as NSString).rangeOfString(title!))
attributedStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.init(name: font, size: 15.0)!, range: (str1 as NSString).rangeOfString(dj!))
label.attributedText = attributedStr
```